# ArcGIS JavaScript API: map loads after pan

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using this.mapa.map.centerAndZoom(center, zoom); with 2 different zooms, 4 and 5.

```
    loadModules([
            'esri/geometry/Point',
        ]).then(([Point]) => {
            switch (evt.target.value) {
                case 'country_cl':
                    center = new Point([-70.71582015815409, -33.47133434146025]);
                    zoom = 4;
                    break;
                case 'country_co':
                    center = new Point([-73.63857136146157, 4.0920688808058]);
                    zoom = 5;
                    break;
                case 'country_mx':
                    center = new Point([-99.94867549215655, 20.55088183550196]);
                    zoom = 5;
                    break;
                }
            this.mapa.map.centerAndZoom(center, zoom);
        });
```

Chile has zoom 4, Colombia and Mexico has 5.

When I pan from Chile to Colombia or Mexico, the map gets blank, and it get loaded after the pan:

[image]

How can I load the map, with the new zoom (4 when comming from 5, and viceversa) before the centerAndZoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :**

first you zoom to the desired level, [setZoom() is a deferred](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#setzoom) so when the function is done, you move the map to the location with [centerAt()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerat)

```js
var map = this.mapa.map;

switch (evt.target.value) {
  ...
}
map.setZoom(zoom).then(function(){
  map.centerAt(center);
});
```

[Here is the jsfiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/m93L6bxw/1/)

Comment: I don't see any change on the behaviour (by commenting my line and uncommenting your block code), mayme it's a local issue in my browser

Comment: Can you post more of your code ?

Comment: By the way, I was talking about the fiddle. Yes I can, but it's an Angular app, with different files, I don't have that code right now, I'll do ASAP.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It first zooms to the desired level, then it pan to the location.

Comment: Much better. Actually I tried to to something like this without success. Thanks.